# Return all row having a maximum value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, group-by, having

I'm using entity framework to connect the database.

I've a table(Let's call it "File") that haves several fields:

ID, Version, XYZ
Primarky key  is based on ID AND Version.
so I can have several line with the same ID but different version(and inversly).

The question is:

How can I, with a LAMBDA expression, ask my Entity Framework, to return me all  last version of a "file".

Example:
Datas:

```
 ID;Version;Other
 1;1;YX
 1;2;YZ
 2;1;AH
 2;2;BH
 2;5;CA
 1;3;AAA
```

Result:

```
 1;3;AAA
 2;5;CA
```

Thank you!

!! The goal is that the database doesn't need to return all rows, and is called only one time, so forget solution like GetAllRows and read the whole collection and save only the latest, or get a list of all possible ID and get the last version foreach in another request. Thanks!

Comment: You explicitly ask for a lambda expression, why is that?

Comment: Because all the project is using this, but it's only a bonus ;)

Comment: If the answer I gave was correct, could you markt it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following LinqToEntites query for this:

```
var result = from f in myEntities.Files
             group f by f.ID into g
             select g.OrderByDescending(f => f.Version).FirstOrDefault();
```

It would perhaps make more sense to use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` but then you get an `UnsupportedException`:

> The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead

Comment: Great, and I will get the whole "entity" or just the "f.Id" that was included in the group condition?

Comment: This query will return the whole entity. The variable `g` is actually an `IEnumerable<File>` with one extra property: `Key`.